# How to resolve “Function1 can't be invoked from Azure WebJobs SDK” error with pre-compiled Azure Function running in local using VS2017?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions

I have a .NET Standard 2.0 class library of pre-compiled Azure Functions. When I run them locally with the CLI(version 1.0.10), I am getting the following error

```
{
    "id": "8425f625-83d9-4bcc-800b-923b691730fd",
    "requestId": "22dcb01e-350e-4b0c-98b5-d2ab069856fd",
    "statusCode": 500,
    "errorCode": 0,
    "message": "'Function1' can't be invoked from Azure WebJobs SDK. Is it missing Azure WebJobs SDK attributes?"
}
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Have you tried to update runtime?